# Angular2 slow initial page load caused of load sequence

Tags: performance, angular, load

I have angular2 project created from [seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed) and I've added several angular components on my initial page. Some of them load images - which is relatively slow, but the actual problem is:

1. I have a bundle which is big (~1mb) and I am currently working on it to make it smaller following [a guide on the subject](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/).
2. The initial load makes just a few requests, loads the bundle (usually ~ 3 seconds) and waits to the Angular application to bootstrap (~1.4 seconds). After that it starts loading all components and load their resources (fonts, images, etc.). Here is how the request looks like:

[image]

I am afraid even after I reduce the bundle size the application would still be bootstrapping for 1.5 seconds without making any requests and then again wait a ~1 seconds for the resources of the components to load. That I assume will lead to about 3+ seconds of load time. With my app being relatively simple I found this not acceptable.

Q1: Is there a way to load the component resources earlier and just reference them on component load?

Q2: Is there a way to make the application bootstrap faster?

I'm open to other suggestions too :)

**Edit:**

I am using AoT compilation, provided with the seed and I have taken steps to lower the size of the `app.js` file. The problem remains with the **gap** between the end of `app.js` downloaded and the first component's resources calls.
[image]

#### UPDATE (2016-12-19):

What I did (for now) is only on the server:

- Enabled the HTTP2 support which resulted in major speed improvement.
- Enabled GZIP which reduced the size of the JS by more than 5 times.

Those server configurations were trivial on NGINX and Apache so its worth giving them a try.

Now although the site loads a lot faster those changes don't solve the initial problems (Problem 1 and Problem 2). Hence I am looking on some other approaches that you may also want to follow if you are in my spot:

- [Prerendering with Gulp](https://preview.npmjs.com/package/angular2-gulp-prerender)
- [Prerendering in Amazon](http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-universal-meet-the-internet-of-the-future-seo-friendly-single-page-web-apps/#prerenderingatbuildtimeuploadprerenderedappstoamazons3)
- [AoT vs JIT compilation](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/08/14/ahead-of-time-compilation-angular-offline-precompilation/) - some insights.

#### UPDATE (2018-06-11):

Here are some materials that helped me boosting the initial load:

- [Angular Performance Workshop - Manfred Steyer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZI_MC3YdSo4&feature=youtu.be)
- [Angular — Faster performance and better user experience with Lazy Loading - by Ashwin Sureshkumar](https://blog.cloudboost.io/angular-faster-performance-and-better-user-experience-with-lazy-loading-a4f323b2cf4a)

In my case the Lazy Loading plays the big role.

Comment: did you managed to make your app faster? I've recently used lazy loading of routes and that improved my load time a little but is still slow

Comment: I updated the answer to include what I've done so far.

Comment: for Enabled the HTTP2 how did you do that? I use cloudflare and I think it includes Enabled the HTTP2.

Comment: It was a server configuration. I don't know how you do that on cloudflare. Google is your friend.

Comment: I am also getting the same problem....U got any solution for the above problem?

Comment: I updated the answer to add the latest materials

Answer (score 4):

Q2: You can make the application bootstrap faster and decrease the bundle size by implementing Ahead of Time compilation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html

Just like it sounds, the templates are precompiled and all the scripts generated beforehand which reduces processing time after the initial load. Additionally, the Angular 2 compiler is not included in your bundle which should cut down on the bundle size itself by a large amount.

Q1: There is lazy loading support of components but I haven't looked into what it entails, someone else may be able to answer that part for you.

Comment: I'm using angular2 with systemjs and using lazy loaded routes. I find the app takes 4 seconds to bootstrap on desktop and 12 seconds on android/mobile and 5 seconds on iPhone. Do you know any good seed apps I could move my app to, for loading speed improvements? I need to get my app loading much faster.

Answer (score 1):

Buy [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) DNS, We were able to reduce load time from 50sec to 4 sec. also able to reduce the refresh speed to around 1 sec.

There is a free version for it, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

also considering the minifying/bundling of the js, enable **gzip** compression at server side will decrease the load time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce as much of your main.js package as possible, the more information in main.js the longer it will take to process it. Check your imports in app.module and use lazy loading.